# Are garbage collected languages vulnerable to buffer overflows?

Tags: garbage-collection, buffer-overflow

I know languages with manual memory management like C/C++ are vulnerable to it but I am not sure about GC based languages like Go and Java? Are there any edge cases where these languages fail or can one definitely say that buffer overflow will never happen in such languages?

Comment: There is no direct relationship. Typical managed code environments tend to be designed that way, to prevent buffer overflows and have garbage collection because there are overlapping considerations. But there is no requirement to have both.

Comment: so we can't say that for certain and it varies from runtime to runtime?

Comment: First, it depends on the language design. There are languages which have garbage collection but still allow unsafe operations. A language like Java does not, but there are nonstandard APIs in some implementations allowing it. Further, it allows interactions with (native) code implemented in a different language, which might have the possibility of buffer overflows. Further, the JVM itself often is implemented in a language which can have buffer overflows.